# How to terminate the execution of Jmeter script/test when assertion is failed - (GUI run)

Tags: jmeter

I have assertion *JSR223 Assertion* sampler with following code:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

JsonSlurper JSON = new JsonSlurper ();
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

def jsonResponse = JSON.parseText(prev.getResponseDataAsString());
def hasError = jsonResponse.hasError

 

if (hasError) {
    AssertionResult.setFailure(true);
 
}
```

How to stop the execution from the assertion sampler based on the `vars.get("JMeterThread.last_sample_ok")` variable, inside in the Assertion sampler, without ading additional elements to the script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Rahul Jadhav for your efforts.

However the honey for me is: `prev.setStopTest(true);`

Or the whole code to stop the script by using Assertion sampler is:

```
if (hasError) {
        AssertionResult.setFailure(true);
        prev.setStopTest(true);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use `If Controller` and `Flow Control Action` after your assertion

[image]

[image]

**OR**

You may use ctx variable from your `JSR223 Assertion` to get access to JMeter Engine to stop test

See details [here](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterContext.html#getEngine--)

Comment: Thanks for the help. And how can I use ctx variable from your JSR223 Assertion?

Comment: check this documentation - https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Assertion